# Itunes connect app description language

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to submit non-english app to iTunes Connect.
Can I provide app description only in language of countries i want it to be available, or do I also have to provide app description in english?

Comment: You can provide all App Store texts only in language you want to support. But in this case make sure you make this language as default.

Answer (score 0):

The description should be in the language you are targeting for.

> "Think globally. The App Store is available in over 150 countries, so
>   you want to localize your app and metadata to attract downloads.
>   **Customers prefer to browse and shop in their native languages**; in your localized description be clear which languages your binary
>   supports. For a list of countries in which the App Store is available,
>   see “App Store Territories.”

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW1)